# Document AI: google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Request contains an invalid argument

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I am getting this error when trying to implement the Document OCR from google cloud in python as explained here: https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/ocr

When I run

```
   result = client.process_document(request=request)
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Niolo/Desktop/untitled/Desktop/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 73, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Niolo/Desktop/untitled/Desktop/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 923, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/Users/Niolo/Desktop/untitled/Desktop/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 826, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
    details = "Request contains an invalid argument."
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1614769280.332675000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:142.250.180.138:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1068,"grpc_message":"Request contains an invalid argument.","grpc_status":3}"
>
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Niolo/Desktop/untitled/Desktop/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/documentai_v1beta3/services/document_processor_service/client.py", line 327, in process_document
    response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,)
  File "/Users/Niolo/Desktop/untitled/Desktop/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 145, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Niolo/Desktop/untitled/Desktop/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 281, in retry_wrapped_func
    return retry_target(
  File "/Users/Niolo/Desktop/untitled/Desktop/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 184, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/Users/Niolo/Desktop/untitled/Desktop/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 75, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Request contains an invalid argument.
```

My full code:

```
import os
# Import the base64 encoding library.


  
project_id= 'your-project-id'
location = 'eu' # Format is 'us' or 'eu'
processor_id = 'your-processor-id' # Create processor in Cloud Console
file_path = '/file_path/invoice.pdf'
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/full_path/your_credentials.json"

def process_document_sample(
        project_id: str, location: str, processor_id: str, file_path: str
):
    from google.cloud import documentai_v1beta3 as documentai

    # Instantiates a client
    client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient()

    # The full resource name of the processor, e.g.:
    # projects/project-id/locations/location/processor/processor-id
    # You must create new processors in the Cloud Console first
    name = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/processors/{processor_id}"

    with open(file_path, "rb") as image:
        image_content = image.read()

    # Read the file into memory
    document = {"content": image_content, "mime_type": "application/pdf"}

    # Configure the process request
    request = {"name": name, "document": document}

    # Recognizes text entities in the PDF document
    result = client.process_document(request=request)

    document = result.document

    print("Document processing complete.")

    # For a full list of Document object attributes, please reference this page: https://googleapis.dev/python/documentai/latest/_modules/google/cloud/documentai_v1beta3/types/document.html#Document

    document_pages = document.pages

    # Read the text recognition output from the processor
    print("The document contains the following paragraphs:")
    for page in document_pages:
        paragraphs = page.paragraphs
        for paragraph in paragraphs:
            paragraph_text = get_text(paragraph.layout, document)
            print(f"Paragraph text: {paragraph_text}")
```

Comment: Are you using any proxy ?

Comment: No I run the code on pycharm

Comment: do you have any proxy settings in your network?

Comment: No under the "Select a protocol to configure" in my mac I don't have anything checked, meaning that I am not using any proxy server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient()` points to US end point by default.

```
in: client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient()
in: print(client.DEFAULT_ENDPOINT)
out: us-documentai.googleapis.com
```

You need to override the api_endpoint to EU for this to work.

```
from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions
    # Set endpoint to EU 
    options = ClientOptions(api_endpoint="eu-documentai.googleapis.com:443")
    # Instantiates a client
    client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient(client_options=options)
```

Here is the full code:

```
import os

# TODO(developer): Uncomment these variables before running the sample.
project_id= 'your-project-id'
location = 'eu' # Format is 'us' or 'eu'
processor_id = 'your-processor-id' # Create processor in Cloud Console
file_path = '/file_path/invoice.pdf'
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/full_path/your_credentials.json"

def process_document_sample(
    project_id: str, location: str, processor_id: str, file_path: str
):
    from google.cloud import documentai_v1beta3 as documentai
    from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions

    # Set endpoint to EU
    options = ClientOptions(api_endpoint="eu-documentai.googleapis.com:443")
    # Instantiates a client
    client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient(client_options=options)

    # The full resource name of the processor, e.g.:
    # projects/project-id/locations/location/processor/processor-id
    # You must create new processors in the Cloud Console first
    name = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/processors/{processor_id}"

    with open(file_path, "rb") as image:
        image_content = image.read()

    # Read the file into memory
    document = {"content": image_content, "mime_type": "application/pdf"}

    # Configure the process request
    request = {"name": name, "document": document}

    # Recognizes text entities in the PDF document
    result = client.process_document(request=request)

    document = result.document

    print("Document processing complete.")

    # For a full list of Document object attributes, please reference this page: https://googleapis.dev/python/documentai/latest/_modules/google/cloud/documentai_v1beta3/types/document.html#Document

    document_pages = document.pages

    # Read the text recognition output from the processor
    print("The document contains the following paragraphs:")
    for page in document_pages:
        paragraphs = page.paragraphs
        for paragraph in paragraphs:
            paragraph_text = get_text(paragraph.layout, document)
            print(f"Paragraph text: {paragraph_text}")
```

Here is a snippet of the output:
[image]

Comment: This error message is really uninformative - hope google sees this and fixes it with a message easy to understand.

Comment: Thank you so much, you really made my day!

Comment: Note: The Python Sample code has all been updated to add the specific endpoint when creating the client https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/process-documents-client-libraries

Comment: I'm getting the same errror with vertex API. The program used to work, I had to shelve it for three weeks. Today, all of a sudden, it's erroring out with the very same message.