# Google DocumentAI Java example fails with io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I **wasted hours** trying the Google Document AI **java** example from https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/quickstart-client-libraries

If you enter your for projectId, location and processorId like this

```
        String projectId = "6493xxxxxxxx";
        String location = "eu";
        String processorId = "74451xxxxxx";
        String filePath = "/Users/schube/Desktop/file.pdf";
```

and run the example, you just get an **InvalidArgumentException**:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.gax.rpc.InvalidArgumentException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:49)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1133)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:31)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1277)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:1038)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:808)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:563)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:533)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener$3.run(DelayedClientCall.java:463)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.delayOrExecute(DelayedClientCall.java:427)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.onClose(DelayedClientCall.java:460)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:557)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:69)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:738)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:717)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: com.google.api.gax.rpc.AsyncTaskException: Asynchronous task failed
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptions.callAndTranslateApiException(ApiExceptions.java:57)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:112)
        at com.google.cloud.documentai.v1.DocumentProcessorServiceClient.processDocument(DocumentProcessorServiceClient.java:232)
        at documentai.QuickStart.quickStart(QuickStart.java:57)
        at documentai.QuickStart.main(QuickStart.java:25)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:535)
    ... 13 more
```

That is really great, because which f*** element is invalid? There are no details in the exception and there is no logfile.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Document AI: google.api\_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Request contains an invalid argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66456548/document-ai-google-api-core-exceptions-invalidargument-400-request-contains-an)

Answer (score 6):

So, turns out after reading this: [What argument is invalid for Google Document AI client library for Node js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64888612/what-argument-is-invalid-for-google-document-ai-client-library-for-node-js)

that if the location is not "us" but "eu", you have to specify an other endpoint.

Oh man, why did they not mention that in the tutorial or the source code? It just says:

```
    // TODO(developer): Replace these variables before running the sample.
    String projectId = "your-project-id";
    String location = "your-project-location"; // Format is "us" or "eu".
    String processorId = "your-processor-id";
    String filePath = "path/to/input/file.pdf";
```

The really should have mentioned that it is not enough to switch to "eu".

So the simple solution is, do not use

```
        try (DocumentProcessorServiceClient client = DocumentProcessorServiceClient.create()) {
```

but

```
        try (DocumentProcessorServiceClient client = DocumentProcessorServiceClient.create(
                DocumentProcessorServiceSettings.newBuilder().setEndpoint("eu-documentai.googleapis.com:443").build())) {
```

Comment: The Sample Docs/Example Code for Node.js has been updated to include these parameters.
https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/process-documents-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-nodejs

Comment: The Java Code Samples have been updated to include the regional endpoint. Docs should update momentarily https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request#documentai_process_document-java